# How to write connection String of Ms SQL Plesk database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, web-hosting, plesk

I am uploading ASP.NET MVC site with database. Can you guide how can i write my connection string in web.config.

[image]

Comment: Do you know https://www.connectionstrings.com ?

Comment: @MatSnow No i dint use it

Comment: OK, there you should be able to get the information you need. You also shoud edit your question and add the type of database you use. (MySQL, MS-SQL, ...)